# Exception sending context in Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

my sonar log says

```
-> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2016.05.24 16:32:58 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory D:\sonarqube-5.5\temp
2016.05.24 16:32:58 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\sonarqube-5.5\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\Users\ic071101\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process1086195450403413700properties
2016.05.24 16:32:59 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
2016.05.24 16:32:59 INFO   es[o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
2016.05.24 16:32:59 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1464087778712] version[1.7.5], pid[6628], build[00f95f4/2016-02-02T09:55:30Z]
2016.05.24 16:32:59 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1464087778712] initializing ...
2016.05.24 16:32:59 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1464087778712] loaded [], sites []
2016.05.24 16:32:59 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1464087778712] using [1] data paths, mounts [[New Volume (D:)]], net usable_space [127.5gb], net total_space [132.3gb], types [NTFS]
2016.05.24 16:33:00 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
2016.05.24 16:33:01 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1464087778712] initialized
2016.05.24 16:33:01 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1464087778712] starting ...
2016.05.24 16:33:01 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1464087778712] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}
2016.05.24 16:33:01 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1464087778712] sonarqube/WZbgeizBRSO_7pWIRoDmyg
2016.05.24 16:33:04 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1464087778712] new_master [sonar-1464087778712][WZbgeizBRSO_7pWIRoDmyg][AAEINBR139986L][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1464087778712}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2016.05.24 16:33:04 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1464087778712] started
2016.05.24 16:33:04 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1464087778712] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
2016.05.24 16:33:06 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2016.05.24 16:33:06 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\sonarqube-5.5\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;D:\sonarqube-5.5\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\ic071101\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process2036280226267501007properties
2016.05.24 16:33:07 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2016.05.24 16:33:07 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: D:\sonarqube-5.5\web
2016.05.24 16:33:07 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.24 16:33:07 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016.05.24 16:33:08 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.5 / 5773a4aab0ef6c0de79d3038e82f8a051049d6d0
2016.05.24 16:33:10 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Starting embedded database on port 9092 with url jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2016.05.24 16:33:10 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database started. Data stored in: D:\sonarqube-5.5\data
2016.05.24 16:33:10 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2016.05.24 16:33:10 WARN  web[o.s.d.DatabaseChecker] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
2016.05.24 16:33:11 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: D:\sonarqube-5.5
2016.05.24 16:33:11 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1464087778712] loaded [], sites []
2016.05.24 16:33:12 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database stopped
2016.05.24 16:33:12 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: File is not a plugin. Please delete it and restart: D:\sonarqube-5.5\extensions\plugins\siemens.plugins.sonarqube-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2016.05.24 16:33:12 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2016.05.24 16:33:12 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2016.05.24 16:33:12 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.24 16:33:12 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2016.05.24 16:33:12 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2016.05.24 16:33:12 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:48) [sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105) ~[sonar-process-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:69) [sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
2016.05.24 16:33:12 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.24 16:33:14 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.24 16:33:14 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.24 16:33:14 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
2016.05.24 16:33:14 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
2016.05.24 16:33:14 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2016.05.24 16:33:14 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1464087778712] stopping ...
2016.05.24 16:33:14 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1464087778712] stopped
2016.05.24 16:33:14 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1464087778712] closing ...
2016.05.24 16:33:14 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1464087778712] closed
2016.05.24 16:33:15 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Need more information

Comment: No one is going to read that. Better format it.

Comment: I've done the formatting, but you should add detail about your settings/environment. As you've no doubt surmised, the log doesn't tell us a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is pretty clear:

```
2016.05.24 16:33:12 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: File is not a plugin. Please delete it and restart: D:\sonarqube-5.5\extensions\plugins\siemens.plugins.sonarqube-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Please delete the `siemens.plugins.sonarqube-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` file that is not a plugin.

Comment: That is right. Is is mandatory for every plugin to have metrics class??

Comment: Not necessarily. But this is another topic.

Comment: log syas my file is not a plugin. what could be possible error while making it?

Comment: This means that the JAR file has not the required SonarQube information in its manifest file. This means that it has not been built correctly. Please look at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Build+plugin

Comment: Thanks alot sir. I am writing my own plugin in this I have to use my own mertics which is in xml form. How to do this?

Comment: please answer this sir its really very urgent ????http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523833/sonarqube-histogram-for-my-metric